# Sublimetext to 2 rows 1 column

Tags: sublimetext2

Is it possible to have a layout in sublime text 2 with two rows at the top and one collumn at the bottom:

```
--------------------
|         |        |
|         |        |
|         |        |
--------------------
|                  |
|                  |
--------------------
```

thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way to do that is to install [Origami](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami) via PackageControl.

> Origami is a new way of thinking about panes in Sublime Text 2 and 3:
>   you tell Sublime Text where you want a new pane, and it makes one for
>   you. It works seamlessly alongside the built-in layout commands.
>
> Ordinarily one uses the commands under View>Layout, or if one is quite
>   intrepid a custom keyboard shortcut can be made to give a specific
>   layout, but both of these solutions were unsatisfactory to me. Perhaps
>   they were to you too! That's what this plugin is for.